# Android: Using Shape to create a Frame for RecyclerView cell, causes Overdraw

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gpu-overdraw

I'm trying to add border/frame for each cell of my RecyclerView. I'm able to successfully achieve that by creating a "Drawable Resource File", and setting that as a background for the cell, as you can see in the following:
.

.

[image]

However, I realized that doing so, **creates extra overdraw** in the page and causes lag in the performance. So I tried to set all the Layout background colors to **@null** to avoid the extra overdraw but I wasn't successful. You can compare the two overdraws in the following(The first pic has Frame and the second one has **no** frame set for it):
.

.

.

.

.

**Overdraw with the Frame:**

[image]
.

.

.

.

.

**Overdraw without the Frame:**
[image]
.

.

The following is the xml code for Drawable Resource File. I set this layout as a background for the RecyclerView Cell.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <stroke
                android:width="0.25dp"
                android:color="#000000" />
            <corners
                android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
                android:topRightRadius="5dp"/>
            <solid
                android:color="@null" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

.

.

Please help me fix this overdraw problem. Also, if you know of any other approach to create frames/border for the cell, without creating extra overdraw, I appreciate if you share that with me.

Comment: Why are you using a selector?

Comment: @user1643723 : I looked over some solutions to add frame for the cell and I tried <selector> and it worked perfectly, except the overdraw problem. Do u know any other way I can add frame to my layout?

Comment: I would use CardView instead of custom frames. Don't create custom views unless absolutely required

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use a `CardView` instead of `RecyclerView` so that you can set `app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"` like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    app:cardElevation="2dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    app:contentPadding="0dp">

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Did this answer help you?

Comment: Thank you Rick. I'll consider this for the future but right now it'll take too much development time out of me if I replace RecyclerView with CardView. So I was wondering if I could use existing features available for RecyclerView to help me with my problem.